# Apache POI 5.2.2 build issues with JDK11

Tags: apache-poi, java-11

I'm running into these errors building Apache POI with JDK 11.  Suggestions to overcome this greatly appreciated.

```
 *[exec]     [javac] Ignoring source, target and bootclasspath as release has been set
 [exec]     [javac] git/poi-5.2.2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/draw/SVGUserAgent.java:66: error: cannot access ViewCSS
 [exec]     [javac]         String viewBoxStr = el.getAttributeNS(null, SVGConstants.SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE);
 [exec]     [javac]                               ^
 [exec]     [javac]   class file for org.w3c.dom.css.ViewCSS not found
 [exec]     [javac] poi-5.2.2/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/draw/SVGUserAgent.java:81: error: cannot access DocumentCSS
 [exec]     [javac]         String a = el.getAttributeNS(null, attr);
 [exec]     [javac]                      ^
 [exec]     [javac]   class file for org.w3c.dom.css.DocumentCSS not found
 [exec]     [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 [exec]     [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 [exec]     [javac] 2 errors*
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build Apache POI from source? Why not just use the pre-build binaries that the project provides?

Comment: I've to make some change to POI for our particular use, so I need to build from source.

Comment: What revision are you building? See also [_Apache POI—How To Build_](https://poi.apache.org/devel/index.html) and [_Can Apache POI be compiled/used with Java 11?_](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N102B0)

Comment: Use gradle instead of ant if you can. POI's continuous integration builds usually use gradle - eg https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/POI/job/POI-DSL-1.11/

Comment: I have no problem building POI with ant or gradle. If you're really stuck, could you try Java 8 for the build instead? The Java 8 build is easier because it doesn't need to worry about JPM modules.